# Pandoc filter to conditionally render some text depending on the value of a variable defined in the metadata section

Tags: pandoc

What I would like to do is write a markdown file containing questions and answers for a class exercise.
In the metadata section of the file I would like to define a variable `render-solution`. In the body of the file, the solutions would be somehow enclosed in custom defined div sections.

Something like this:

```
---
title: My Document
render-solution: yes
---

## Task 1
A difficult problem

::: { .conditional-render }
## Solution 1
Here is the solution
:::
```

Then a custom filter would check the value of the `render-solution`variable and if the value is `yes`, then the contents of the custom div sections (containing the solutions) are rendered. If the value of the variable is `no`, then the contents of the div sections are not rendered.

I am pretty sure, that this can be done with pandoc filters, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

I tried the following pandoc filter

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pandocfilters import toJSONFilter, Str, Para, Div

def conditional_render(key, value, format, meta):
    if key == 'Div':
        [[ident, classes, kvs], content] = value
        if 'conditional-render' in classes:
            if meta['render-solution']['c'] == "yes":
                return Div([ident, classes, kvs], content)
            else:
                return []

if __name__ == "__main__":
    toJSONFilter(conditional_render)
```

But it didn't work. The section doesn't get rendered independently of the value of `render-solution`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters) here, because Lua is built-in and the filter is short in the case at hand:

```lua
function Pandoc (doc)
  local render_solutions = doc.meta['render-solutions']
  return doc:walk {
    Div = function (div)
      if div.classes:includes 'conditional-render' then
        return render_solutions and
          div.content or -- unwrap the div, just return the contents
          {}             -- otherwise return an empty list of elements
      end
    end
  }
end
```

The `walk` function is basically a filter-in-a-filter. The extra complexity is needed because we first need to get the value from the metadata.

Comment: Hi tarleb, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. The error message was `./myfilter.lua:7: function arguments expected near 'or'`. Since I'm not expert in lua, I don't really know what that means.

Comment: @RafaelMayoral sorry, there was a typo (`:` vs `.`). Should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks. No error message anymore, but it still doesn't really work. The solutions are rendered independently of the value of render-solutions.

Comment: I think the problem is `render-solution` vs `render-solutions` (singular/plural). Try to change either the code or the metadata.

Comment: Also, try with `false` instead of `no`. YAML is... weird in that regard.

Comment: Solved! The trick was using `False` and `True`. The lua filter works now (after also correcting the `:`with `.`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found the way to do this using panflute in python.

The markdown file is:

```
---
title: "The title"
author: "Some author"
format: pdf
lang: "en"
render-solutions: True
---

# Header 1

## Task 1

A difficult problem

::: solution
### Solution
The first solution
:::

## Task 2

An even harder problem

::: solution
### Solution
The second solution
:::
```

And the filter is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import panflute as pf

def my_filter(elem, doc):
    if doc.get_metadata('render-solutions') == True:
        if isinstance(elem, pf.Div) and 'solution' in elem.classes:
            return elem
    elif doc.get_metadata('render-solutions') == False:
        if isinstance(elem, pf.Div) and 'solution' in elem.classes:
            return []
    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Call the main function
    pf.toJSONFilter(my_filter)
```

Now, the `div` with the solutions will only be rendered when `render-solutions` is `True`. When `render-solutions` is `False` the divs will be discarded.

The solution using the lua filter works as well. Thanks to @tarleb.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @tarleb for his lua filter.
In the meantime, I have come up with a not very good solution, which I can use until I understand the rest.

```
---
title: "A test file"
render-solutions: "yes"
---

## Task 1
A difficult question

::: solution_yes
## Solution
This is the solution
:::
```

And then I can use a simple filter

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pandocfilters import toJSONFilter, Str, Para, Div

def conditional_render(key, value, format, meta):
    if key == 'Div' :
        [[ident, classes, kvs], content] = value
        if 'solution_yes' in classes:
            return Div([ident, classes, kvs], content)
        else:
            return []

if __name__ == "__main__":
    toJSONFilter(conditional_render)
```

This works, but I have to change all divs from `solution_yes` to something else when I don't want the solutions rendered. Not efficient and error-prone.

The problem is that I still don't know how to access the contents of the meta section correctly. And of course, I still don't know lua.